# Ensuring object in spark streaming runs on specific node

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

Say you have a spark streaming setup such as

```
JavaReceiverInputDStream<...> rndLists = jssc.receiverStream(new JavaRandomReceiver(...));

rndLists.map(new NeuralNetMapper(...))
    .foreach(new JavaSyncBarrier(...));
```

Is there any way of ensuring that, say, a JavaRandomReceiver and JavaSyncBarrier get distributed to the same node ? Or is this even a question that makes sense ?

Some information as to how spark-streaming distributes work across a cluster would also be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can try custom partitioning. Check this link:

https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/learning-spark/9781449359034/ch04.html